# How can i open a form everytime a textbox is focused?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, wce

im developing a keyboard to a touchscreen display, i need to know how can i program a generic code that everytime any textbox is focused, the form(keyboard) opens. I know i could put in the event focus of every single textbox, but i want to  do a generic code. Im working with WCE8 and .net compact framework 3.5.

Comment: Please add some code..

Comment: the keyboard is working, i just need to know if there is something i can do to open the form everytime a textbox is focused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the control type textbox in your control and gives them the click event with a foreach, for instance

```
foreach(Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if(ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ctrl.Click += new EventHandler(OpenSecondForm_Click); 
            }
        }

private void OpenSecondForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
    }
```

in this way, every time you focused any textbox,it will open a second form, I hope this can help you.

Comment: after initialize the form, you can add that code in the constructor after InitializeComponent() or in load event, if  you are using winforms or wpf in your keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own custom control and override the `OnGotFocus` function

```
public partial class FocusTextBox : TextBox {
    public FocusTextBox() {}

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) {
        // Your code to open the keyboard here

        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RafaelFerronato you use the `FocusTextBox` class instead of `TextBox` class! (you can right click into your `InitializeComponent()` method inside your form's constructor and select `Go To Definition`, there, change `System.Windows.Forms.Controls.TextBox` to `{Namespace}.FocusTextBox`)